# How to dynamically color regions on your SVG map based on the disease counts

Tags: laravel, svg

I have this code that counts the selected disease option from the dropdown for each purok or region of a barangay or an area

```
$diseaseCounts = HouseholdHead::whereHas('respondents.diseases', function ($query) use ($selectedDiseaseId) {
    $query->where('disease_id', $selectedDiseaseId);
})->with('puroks')->groupBy('purok_id')->selectRaw('count(*) as count, purok_id')->get();
```

I have svg code from my choropleth map. my svg map has regions and these regions are the puroks. The polygons in my svg map has id for the unique identifier for each purok for example Purok 1 , Purok 2 etc.

```
<g id="Purok_1" data-name="Purok 1">
     <polygon   id="purok1" onmouseover="displayName('Purok 1')"
         points="7 289.33 25.29 289.33 41.36 289.33 60.64 289.33 86 276.33 93 259.33 99 247.33 109 237.33 125.57 237.33 155 268.33 155 249.47 160 233.33 167 217.33 167 138.26 108 158.33 117 165.33 125 172.33 129 176.33 131 192.33 97 218.33 68 230.33 43 241.33 12 258.33 1 265.33 1 277.76 7 289.33" />
</g>
```

I want to associate the results from diseaseCounts to my svg map, and I need to figure out how.

For example when the user selects a disease from the option in the dropdown, and the result is like this:  Purok 1 has 10 of the selected disease, Purok 2 has 20 etc.

I want to put colors of the regions on the map that have the disease in their purok with corresponding colors for example lower than 10 is green, higher than 10 is yellow and more than 20 is red. Is it possible?